# Move a file without releasing lock

Tags: java, nio, move, filelock

I am using Java NIO in spring batch application. The application looks in a directory (e.g. /shared/inbox) where /shared is network shared disk among all instances of applications running on different JVMs.

To avoid multiple threads reading same files, in my ItemReader I take a FileLock and avoid other threads to read from it.

While I am done reading, I want to move the file to another directory (e.g. /shared/archive). But the Files.move method cannot do that unless I give up the FileLocl, and if I give up the lock, I run the risk of some other thread picking the file.

Question is, can I move the file from inbox to archive without giving up the FileLock?

Comment: Well evidently not. Using a shared folder won't help.

Comment: Can't you just copy the file, put a lock on the new file then release the old lock?

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by creating another tmp file to indicate other threads of my application that the file is already picked up by a thread. Then I release the lock and move the file. Not elegant, but it does the job for now.

Comment: @OverlyOptimized thanks for sharing your solution man. I'm also facing the same problem. Please let me know if you came up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the file using `java.nio.channels.FileChannel`

```
private static void copyFileUsingFileChannels(File source, File dest)throws IOException {
    FileChannel inputChannel = null;
    FileChannel outputChannel = null;
    try {
        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
        outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();

        outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
    } finally {
        inputChannel.close();
        outputChannel.close();
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: But the original file is not yet deleted

Comment: This does not move the file. It copies it. Doesn't answer the question that was asked.